# UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity without IdentityType

Tags: c#, ldap, ldap-query

I have found that you can call the FindByIdentity method with or without the IdentityType argument

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.findbyidentity(v=vs.110).aspx

I have found on here that if you include the IdentityType.Name it searches the CN field in AD, IdentityType.SamAccountName is self explanatory.

We have code that does not include the IdentityType.name argument.

UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "00471");

What field(s) does that search in AD?

For most searches this works perfect for us.  I just came across a search that is erroring with the error that it's returning more than one results. Not knowing what fields it's searching I can't figure out how it's finding more than one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it search against ALL Types mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.identitytype?view=netframework-4.7.2